# Problem with PerpetuumSoft ReportViewer 2008 for Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, reportviewer

First, I have filed for support from PerpetuumSoft. They have not been helpful.

I have been able to create a new project and get the reportviewer to load our reports with no problems.

But, when I try to add the report viewer to an existing silverlight + ria services app. I get this:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object
>   sendState) at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(Object sendState)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String
>   action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] args,
>   IAsyncResult result) at
>   PerpetuumSoft.ReportingServices.Viewer.Client.ReportService.ReportServiceClient.ReportServiceClientChannel.EndListExportsFormats(ExceptionDetailBase&
>   ReportError, IAsyncResult result) at
>   PerpetuumSoft.ReportingServices.Viewer.Client.ReportService.ReportServiceClient.PerpetuumSoft.ReportingServices.Viewer.Client.ReportService.IReportService.EndListExportsFormats(ExceptionDetailBase&
>   ReportError, IAsyncResult result) at
>   PerpetuumSoft.ReportingServices.Viewer.Client.ReportService.ReportServiceClient.OnEndListExportsFormats(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult
>   result)

Nothing works, no matter what. I have verified again and again the urls for the WCF report service and SQL reporting services.

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but are there any ideas?

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I am having the same issue with this product.

Comment: Actually I have now resolved it by following the advice in the answer below.  I had incorrectly specified the wrong assembly name in the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this issue appears because of wrong type name of Service in

```
<PerpetuumSoftServices> section of web.config file.
<Service Type="<reportservice type name with namespace>, <assembly name>">
```

, where

```
<assembly name> you may find in Application properties,
<reportservice type name with namespace> is namespace + class name from ReportService.svc.cs file.
```

For example:

```
<Service Type="SilverlightApplication.Web.ReportService, SilverlightApplication.Web">
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the problem.